# how to pass id from view to controller using AJAX on .click()

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working on Laravel 5.2 and I want to send `book_id` as the user clicks on *Add to Cart* button but I'm not able to do so.

```
<button id="cart" class="btnbuy btn-hvr-ripple-out">ADD TO CART</button>
```

Ajax Function

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#cart").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:'get',
            url: "/addcart/{id}",
            contentType:'application/json',
            data:{ id :"{{$value->book_id}}"},
                    success: function(data){
                alert(data.msg);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Routes.php

```
/*cart*/
Route::get('/addcart','AjaxOperationController@addcart');
```

Controller

```
public function addcart(Request $request)
{
    $id=request->id;
    if ($request->session()->has('userId')) 
    {
        $user_id=$request->session()->get('userId');
        $add_to_cart=DB::insert('insert into cart_master (user_id, book_id) values(?,?)',[$user_id,$id]);
        return response()->json('msg'=>'Product has been added to cart! :)');
    }
    else
    {
        return response()->json('msg'=>'Please Login first to access cart! :)');
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are passing extra parameter to url and also sending data to the function

```/addcart/{id}}```.


Also you have to write this as follows
```data:{ id :"{{$value->book_id}}"}``` => no need to add extra quotes.

Comment: extra parameter??

Comment: ```/addcart/{id}}``` => this means you are passing some querystring to the function (get parameter)

Comment: hey got rid of error but alert is not displaying.. :(

Comment: check in console, that you really getting success response or error.

Comment: Console is giving me 500 error in my other ajax function for category and authors.

Answer (score 0):

You're sending the data array as a string instead of javascript object.

```
data:'{"id":"{{$value->book_id}}"}',
```

Send it as an object instead:

```
data: {
          id : "{{$value->book_id}}"
      }
```

Comment: You need to remove extra curly brace from code ```id : "{{$value->book_id}}"}```

Comment: not working bro got method not allowed here exception :(

Comment: @BhavikBamania, did you remove the extra curly brace as kishor said?

Comment: I think at `url: "/addcart/{id}}",` you're missing an left curly brace before id

Comment: nope that gives assumed constant id error and that was my mistake so I've removed it in my new edit

Comment: @BhavikBamania that's because `id` is a variable and not a constant. Use `{{ $i }}` and see if it works.

Comment: That's because there is no `$id` variable defined. If this variable comes from a request or something, make sure to get the proper values and check for null.

Answer (score 0):

I supposed that `"{{$value->book_id}}"` is coming from php.
You need to change you code as follows:

Ajax call :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#cart").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:'get',
            url: "addcart/",
            contentType:'application/json',
            data:{ id :"{{$value->book_id}}"},
            success: function(data){
                alert(data.msg);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Route:

```
Route::get('addcart','AjaxOperationController@addcart');
```

Use :

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Controller:

```
public function addcart(Request $request)
{
    $id=request->input("id");
    if ($request->session()->has('userId')) 
    {
        $user_id=$request->session()->get('userId');
        $add_to_cart=DB::insert('insert into cart_master (user_id, book_id) values(?,?)',[$user_id,$id]);
        return response()->json('msg'=>'Product has been added to cart! :)');
    }
    else
    {
        return response()->json('msg'=>'Please Login first to access cart! :)');
    }
}
```

Comment: still no :'( I dont know why the hell I'm getting 500 error MethodNotAllowedHere exception :(

Comment: @BhavikBamania : check you routes. Are you following all naming conventions of Laravel? I done with an ajax demo and then uploaded this answer.

Comment: I guess It got messed up with my other ajax function if it is working well then i guess I should use some other controller for this function??

Comment: @BhavikBamania : do one thing. write another demo function in your controller, and call it from your ajax using get method, return json response and try to alert it. if you get success, then just copy paste the code inside that function.

Comment: Undefined variable: value (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\bookbucket\laravel\resources\views\bookdetail.blade.php)
got this error :( it is mentioning  $value as undefined I've checked the ending statements they all are fine but still this..

Comment: In your ajax, ```$value``` is a php variable, so you have to formulate it that how to pass a php variable to javascript in your view.